# Nginx not working with domain/url that points to server IP

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu, https, http-headers

The configuration I have set (below) works for `localhost` but not for my domain. The goal is to access port 3000 externally with **basic auth** so only I can access it. When I go to `localhost`, it is upgraded to `https`, I have to complete the authentication, and then port 3000 is shown, just as it's meant to. However, going to `api.example.com` does not prompt authentication, does not upgrade the connection, and just shows `Invalid Host header`. When I open port 3000 for port forwarding and go to `api.example.com:3000`, I can access the port, but it doesn't require authentication, doesn't use `https`, and my goal is to avoid port forwarding. This configuration came from instructions so I don't know what could be the issue. Why is my subdomain not working with this config?

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

upstream supabase {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name localhost *host IP* api.example.com;
    access_log  off;
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name localhost *host IP* api.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/api.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/api.example.com/privkey.pem;

    # STUDIO
    location / {
        auth_basic "Authentication Required";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://supabase;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Firewall:

```
 sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80/tcp (Nginx HTTP)        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
8000                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full)    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443/tcp (Nginx HTTPS)      ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp (Nginx HTTP (v6))   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
8000 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (Nginx HTTPS (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: Your http server block is missing the server name.

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re talking about. Both server blocks have `server_name`.

Comment: Is there anything in nginx `error.log`?

Comment: I took a look at the error log and it looks like it is saying this every time: `server name "http://api.example.com" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:6`. I also made the change that an answer suggested and now, instead of `Invalid Host Header`, going to `api.example.com` gives `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.

Comment: A timeout usually indicates a firewall issue.

Comment: That’s what I thought too but the Firewall is set up correctly and I even disabled it to see if that would work.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I added my UFW Firewall configuration to the bottom of the question. I don't think it's the cause of the problem because, even with the Firewall disabled, the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Your server block for port 80 has only the name `localhost` configured.

```
server_name localhost;
```

The domain `api.example.com` is missing here. So the request to that domain via HTTP is captured by the default server block from the nginx default configuration.

Add the domain here, as you did it in the SSL server block.

```
server_name localhost api.example.com;
```

Comment: I've added that (and updated it in the question) but it still is not working. I took a look at the error log and it looks like it is saying this every time: `server name "http://api.example.com" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:6`

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that your DNS name really is api.example.com - but it is good practice to NOT publish that here. However this error is expected if you supply an invalid hostname - i.e. one containing characters other than a-z, 0-9, '.' and '-'. This might not be deliberate - omitting a trailing ';' from the list of names will probably have the same result. In such a scenario nginx will refuse to load a configuration file. Its *always* a good idea to test your config with `nginx -t` before applying; 'systemctl reload nginx' won't tell you you have a bad config.